# Rails 'errors' variable (on form validation, etc)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation, ruby-on-rails-3

I'm kinda new to rails (3) and I stumbled upon a small... doorstep. Does the model *automatically* create the "errors" variable when the verification fails (for a lack of better term)? If so, is there a way to make it look neater somehow? Because the output can sometimes be like:

> Username can't be less than 5 characters long
>
> Username can't be blank
>
> Username is ugly.

And I don't think that could look so much better.

P.S: The errors were from the top of my head, so they might not be too accurate.

(I'll keep you posted if I find something out. :)

Comment: Sorry! There, I marked it as answered (a little later than you might have wished for). I'm new to stackoverflow. So, I'm still adjusting. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just use the 'message' method

```
class Account < ActiveRecord::Base
  validates_exclusion_of :subdomain, :in => %w(www us ca jp),
  :message => "Subdomain %{value} is reserved."
end
```

Have a look here : http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations_callbacks.html

Comment: Okay, I'm just wondering if the same could be accomplished with:

validates :subdomain, :uniqueness => true, :message => "Subdomain %{value} is reserved."

Comment: you can create your own validators through methods, it's in the link as well.

Comment: here: http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations_callbacks.html#creating-custom-validation-methods